# Create two life-cycle configuration scripts for an Amazon sagemaker notebook

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I have two life-cycle scripts doing two logic blocks, technically, all can be a single script by definition (just a shell script to be run at start of the instance).

In reality, my two lifecycles are very different for multiple notebooks, one is generic: changes only per technical environment: dev, prod, sandbox; But the other is more specific: per region and per user.

It would be so difficult to refactor existing code, so that the already present life-cycle (generic one) be this time session specific to user/region.

Plus, at runtime, based on user choice, a new sagemaker can have either policy or both or none.

I passed some time reading AWS documentation but it seems only one life-cycle can be attached to one sagemaker notebook.

Is there a workaround ?